# Can a figure tag contain an anchor tag wrapping the image?

Tags: html, figure

I am trying to create a figure tag that has inside an anchor tag wrapping the image. I was wondering if that structure is legal or not. Here is the code showing how I want it to work.

```
<figure>
   <a href="/my-picture">
       <img src="img/picture.jpg" alt="My picture">
   </a>
   <figcaption>
       My picture
   </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Any place I can check these doubts? @Rasel

Comment: You can validate your markup at http://validator.nu

Comment: For information: You cannot wrap the `figcaption` alone with an anchor. However, you can put the anchor within the `figcaption`. Vaild alternative as stated below, you wrap the entire `figure` with an anchor.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Validator says it's proper structure, so yes.

When it comes to semantic I don't see any problem, however always remember that in HTML5 you can wrap whole figure in a link which might be of use as in most of the case you want to wrap description also.

I used this to validate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>a</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <figure>
      <a href="/my-picture">
        <img src="img/picture.jpg" alt="My picture">
      </a>
      <figcaption>
        My picture
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Current WHATWG spec says that `<a>` element is `transparent` but it cannot contain interactive elements. As a result, you can wrap nearly anything non-interactive in `<a>` and it will be valid. (Obviously, `<a>` cannot be direct child of `e.g. <ul>` or `<table>` elements.)